# In ZIO, is there a way to transform an IO[Nothing, T] to T, and if not, why not?

Tags: scala, scalaz, zio

After considering errors and converting `IO[E, T]` to an `IO[Nothing, T]` we may directly refer to the value as being of type `T` instead of `IO[Nothing, T]`. This allows us to return a value of type `T` without resorting to the use of `var` and `IO.map`. Is there a way to do this, and if not, why not?

No solution was found in the current README of ZIO.

Comment: As for "Why not?": The idea is to have functions being "non-pure" part of that function's type signature. So anything that interacts with an `IO` has to be an `IO` itself. If you have used `Future` in plain Scala, that is kind of the same situation: If anything the function does involves Futures, it itself has to return a Future. You can "hide" that by calling `Await.result` inside, but that is highly discouraged. Only the ultimate caller should do that if necessary. Same with `IO`. You could call `unsafeRun` to "extract" the value, but you really should not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IO[E, T]` is just a description of a program that can either return an error `E` or produce a value `T`.

To actually produce this value you need to run this program.

ZIO by design encourages pushing the impure side effects to the very edge of your program which is the `main` function. In fact you don't need to explicitly call `unsafeRun` anywhere in your code, as ZIO's `App` trait takes care of this for you.

That being said, if you still need to do it, say becouse you're not ready to refactor your whole application, you can use the `RTS` trait (RTS stands for runtime system).

```
import scalaz.zio._

class SomeService extends RTS {

  val pureProgram: IO[Nothing, String] = ???

  // will throw if pureProgram returns error branch
  def impureMethod: String {
    println("Part of my program is pure, but not all of it")
    unsafeRun(pureProgram)
  }
}
```

See ZIO RTS [Scaladoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalaz/scalaz-zio_2.12/0.2.8/scalaz/zio/RTS.html) for other run methods.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to implement a *pure* function that takes `IO[Nothing, T]` and returns `T`.

It is so because the first type argument of ZIO's `IO[_, _]` describes *errors* that can happen inside an `IO`-wrapped computation. `IO[Nothing, T]` describes a computation that cannot fail, but still it encapsulates a *side-effectful* computation. That is why you cannot get value of type `T` outside of it in a *pure* function.

Just talking about physical possibility, since Scala is not a pure language, you have a possibility to write a function that takes `IO[Nothing, T]` and returns `T` but you are really discouraged to do this by the design and ideology of ZIO.

Answer (score 3):

For all the folks looking for answer in 2019 - there's been a minor change in the API.

```
import scalaz.zio._

object RTS extends DefaultRuntime

class Service {
  val program: UIO[String] = ???

  def mixPureImpure: String = {
    println("Calling service")
    RTS.unsafeRun(program)
  }
}
```